# Отказ в соединении с бд в докере

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, mysqli, docker

Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /var/www/html/index.php on line 8
conn failedConnection refused

```
webdev:
  php:
     Dockerfile
     index.php
  docker-compose.yml

Dockerfile:
 FROM php:7.3.3-apache
 RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
 RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
 EXPOSE 80

docker-compose.yml
 version: '3'
 services:
   web:
    build:
     context: ./php
     dockerfile: Dockerfile
     container_name: php73
   depends_on:
     - db
   volumes:
     - ./php:/var/www/html
   ports:
     - 8000:80 
 db:
   container_name: mysql8
   image: mysql:8.0
   command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
   restart: always
   environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: t_db
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass
   ports:
     - 6033:3306

  index.php
  <?php

   $host = 'db';
   $user = 'user';
   $password = 'pass';
   $db = 't_db';

   $conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db);

   if($conn->connect_error) {
     echo 'conn failed' . $conn->connect_error;
   }else{
    echo "Successfully connected";
   }
```

Отказано в соединении.

Comment: 6033:3306 -> 3306:3306

Comment: мне кажется, что вы перепутали внутренний порт контейнера с бд. По идее он тоже должен быть 3306

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поменяйте внутренний порт бд в файле docker-compose.yml с 6033 на 3306. Вот скрин с докерфайла образа бд.
[image: Скрин с Dockerfile образа mysql:8.0]